# Trying to implement the TornadoFX "Motivational example"

Tags: kotlin, javafx, delegates, tornadofx

I'm trying to implement the motivational example from this page: https://docs.tornadofx.io/0_subsection/1_why_tornadofx

For this I need a data class Person as defined here:

```
class Person(id: Int, name: String, birthday: LocalDate) {
    val idProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(id)
    var id by idProperty

    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty(name)
    var name by nameProperty

    val birthdayProperty = SimpleObjectProperty(birthday)
    var birthday by birthdayProperty

    val age: Int get() = Period.between(birthday, LocalDate.now()).years
}
```

To do this it was neccessary to make the following imports:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.Period
```

However, if I try to run the example I get the following error:

```
Kotlin: Property delegate must have a 'getValue(Person, KProperty<*>)' method. None of the following functions is suitable: 
public open fun getValue(): Int! defined in javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty
```

I can circumvent this by not using delegate types and setting the properties like this:

```
    val idProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(id)
    var id: Int
        get() = idProperty.value
        set(value) { idProperty.value = value}
```

But that seems to defeat the point of using delegates in TornadoFX when this is their motivational example for using it.

Here's what I found on delegate types: https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part2/Property_Delegates.html

That doesn't help with getting the shorthand of  `var id by idProperty` to work though.

Can somebody point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to also import the following:

```kotlin
import tornadofx.getValue
import tornadofx.setValue
```

Those are extension operator functions defined for various types in JavaFX (e.g., properties, observable values, etc.) so that those types can be used as delegates. But those function aren't defined *in* those types, thus the need for the additional imports.